# Undefined WIN32 messages

Tags: c++, winapi, message

I am getting strange input in my windows message callback.

Besides all the normal messages, like `WM_SIZE`, which work fine, there are some messages that do not appear in any table, like [this one](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages).  And they are not defined as [error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx), either.

The messages are: (decimal / hex)

- 356 / 0164 (wParam: 0, lParam: 5760884)
- 49291 / c08b (wParam: 4294967292 or 0, lParam: 0)
- 49348 / c0c4 (wParam: 0, lParam: 0)

Does anybody know what they mean, or why I am gettting them?

Comment: Unclear, why you think that messages and error codes are somehow related. I don't know, what the first message is, but the final two are application-private messages (`WM_APP` + x). They are defined by the receiver, and do not have global meaning.

Comment: It's not surprising that you receive windows messages. Whether the ones you receive are to be expected, or have been sent by mistake, who can say. Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: 0x164 appears to be [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775839(v=vs.85).aspx). Are you monitoring messages on a combobox?

Comment: Some windows messages are indeed undocumented, tends to be a crime committed 25+ years ago that they can never fix again.  Messages >= 0xc000 are pretty normal, RegisterWindowMessage() produces them.  These messages mean something to DefWindowProc or a sub-classed window procedure, they are not intended for your consumption.

Comment: Any messages that you are not expecting and do not handle should be forwarded on to DefWindowProc. It is not clear to me what actual problem you are having. You don't need to handle every message that you receive; some of them may not be intended for the application to handle. Why would it be surprising that there are undocumented messages intended for the operating system's private use?

Comment: Heck, Microsoft is known to to use a similar technique of sending random ID's to drivers - "OS> do you support feature 49348? driver> Yes. OS>No you don't, I made that number up.". The technique tells the OS whether third-party code is coded against the documented API's. If you start doing random things in response to unknown messages, Windows will know your program must be run in a restricted compatibility environment.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, the reason i wanted to know what these were was because they might have helped identify I problem i was having, and also just to know what is going on (i find that generally a good idea when doing things).
I can now pass on the messages knowing they aren't gonna help me at all with peace of mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Win32 documentation:

> The following are the ranges of message numbers.
>
> ```
> Range                           Meaning
>
> 0 through WM_USER–1             Messages reserved for use by the system.
> WM_USER through 0x7FFF          Integer messages for use by private window classes.
> WM_APP (0x8000) through 0xBFFF  Messages available for use by applications.
> 0xC000 through 0xFFFF           String messages for use by applications.
> Greater than 0xFFFF             Reserved by the system.
> ```
>
> Message numbers in the first range (0 through WM_USER –1) are defined by the system. Values in this range that are not explicitly defined are reserved by the system.
>
> Message numbers in the second range (WM_USER through 0x7FFF) can be defined and used by an application to send messages within a private window class. These values cannot be used to define messages that are meaningful throughout an application because some predefined window classes already define values in this range. For example, predefined control classes such as BUTTON, EDIT, LISTBOX, and COMBOBOX may use these values. Messages in this range should not be sent to other applications unless the applications have been designed to exchange messages and to attach the same meaning to the message numbers.
>
> Message numbers in the third range (0x8000 through 0xBFFF) are available for applications to use as private messages. Messages in this range do not conflict with system messages.
>
> Message numbers in the fourth range (0xC000 through 0xFFFF) are defined at run time when an application calls the RegisterWindowMessage function to retrieve a message number for a string. All applications that register the same string can use the associated message number for exchanging messages. The actual message number, however, is not a constant and cannot be assumed to be the same between different sessions.
>
> Message numbers in the fifth range (greater than 0xFFFF) are reserved by the system.

Where [`WM_USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931.aspx) is 0x0400.

So,

- 356 (0x164) is a system reserved message. Specifically, it is [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775839.aspx).
- 49291 (0xC08B) and 49348 (0xC0C4) are string messages that have been registered with [`RegisterWindowMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947.aspx) at runtime. You *may* be able to use [`GetClipboardFormatName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649040.aspx) to retrieve the original string value used for the registration, as `RegisterWindowMessage()` and [`RegisterClipboardFormat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649049.aspx) *usually* share a common atom table.